# How do I fix Windows 10 apps from launching the store instead of the actual app?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

I've got a few Windows 10 applications (Instagram, Flipboard, Kali Linux, etc,.) that after launching from the start menu instead of launching the actual app instead launches the windows store app and displays the "Downloads and updates" view.

If I launch the app from the Windows Store app, the application does actually run.  How do I fix this issue?

---

A few more details:

- I can launch the application correctly from the store
- If pinned to the taskbar, the application correctly launches
- If launched from the Start menu (not the "pinned" display) the app **incorrectly** launches
- If launched from the Start menu "pinned" display the app also **incorrectly** launches
- Post restart of the system, the affected application is **no longer present** in the start menu
- If I press the start menu, type in the application name, and then press enter, the application launches properly

Answer (score 3):

This is a sign of app metadata getting damaged.

Try resetting the app (from the App and Features part of Settings). If that failed, uninstall and reinstall the app.

This solution is for Windows v1709 and earlier only. 1803 is not stable enough at this time.

#### To reset an app:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to open the quick access menu.
2. Select "Apps and Feature" (which should be on the top)
3. Find the affected app and select it.
4. Click on the "Advanced options" hyperlink that just appeared.
5. In the next screen, press the "Reset" button.

#### To wipe-and-reload an app:

1. Uninstall it.

   1. Right-click on its tile and select "Uninstall". proceed to the next step whether you find an uninstall option or not.
   2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to open the quick access menu.
   3. Select "Apps and Feature" (which should be on the top)
   4. Find the affected app and select it. If you can't find it, skip the next step.
   5. Click on the "Uninstall" button.
2. Open Microsoft Store
3. If an update for Microsoft Store is available, install it.
4. Navigate to the page corresponding to your app. Do this using the search or via the library. Please don't use any other method.
5. If Microsoft Store thinks the app is still installed, click on "Uninstall" button.
6. Have every user account on you computer repeat the steps above.
7. Go back to Microsoft Store and install it.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment that "1803 is not stable enough" - does this mean that using this specific solution does not actually work as advertised on 1803? Have you tested this specific thing on 1803, or are you just generically throwing 1803 under the bus?

Comment: @allquixotic I have tested 1709 extensively in a production environment. I have enough confidence that there is a good chance this solution works on it. As for 1803, (1) my experience with it has not been extensive, (2) it is not released to Semi-Annual Channel (non-targeted) yet (which means Microsoft doesn't have enough confidence) and (3) it has a reputation for being the buggiest Windows 10 version yet. Hence, I do not have enough confidence in the solution working on 1803.

Comment: Doing this on 1709 doesn't resolve my issue.  Where is metadata for the apps located?  Could there be residual files/metadata that isn't getting cleaned?

Comment: What is interesting, is that some of the apps work just fine.  And it doesn't seem to be developer biased either.  I.e. Trello works just fine, but Spotify doesn't.  Weather works fine, but MSN Sports doesn't.  Weird.

Comment: So, you are saying that neither resetting nor the wipe-and-reload helped you? Hm... I understanding why resetting might not work, but the wipe-and-reload not working is ... literally impossible. Please make sure you reported everything that might impact the answer in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't think of any more details to give :/  What other information would you need?

Comment: @FleetCommand I've updated my post with a few more details as best as I could see.